# condition to save workbook only when open

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I have this code to autosave a workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()



Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Save1"



End Sub

Sub Save1()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

Problem is now it keeps opening to save. Anyone know what the syntax is to let it save only when its open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you never stop the timer - it stays active even if you close the workbook. When the minute is over, VBA want to call a Sub (`Save1`) that is currently not available (as the workbook is closed), so VBA asks Excel to open the file so that it can execute the routine.

It will not help you if you would somehow add a check if the workbook is open because at that time, it *is* already open again.

What you need to do is to stop your timer when you close the workbook. The event for that is `Workbook_BeforeClose`. Now stopping a timer in VBA is a little bit tricky: You call the `Application.OnTime`-method again, and you have to provide the exact parameter that you issued when the timer was set the last time: The name of the routine *and* the time need to match. The only difference is that you set the 4th parameter (`Schedule`) to False.

As a consequence, your code need to keep track what time was provided at the last call to `OnTime`. Have a look to the following code:

In the Workbook-Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    StopTimer
End Sub
```

In a regular code module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FireTime As Variant     ' This holds the time when Ontime was called the last time

Sub StartTimer()
    FireTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime FireTime, "Save1"
    ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = FireTime
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    If Not IsEmpty(FireTime) Then
        Application.OnTime FireTime, "Save1", , Schedule:=False
        FireTime = Empty
    End If
End Sub

Sub Save1()
    Debug.Print "tick"
    ' put your actions here, eg saving 
    StartTimer  ' Schedule the next Timer event
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Save1",, False
End Sub
```

Comment: still is auto opening, take a look  https://villaron-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/donnovan_villaron_com_au/ESrWliFEru5EoFvriGb5BzAB_JK2z5s903GwwLsXIpl8Fg?e=40g6Y4

Comment: The file you gave does not have the code for the workbook_open. I added it and tested the code and it works fine. Is it possible you are working with 2 files?